# Validating Group Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am designing a fitness web app which allows you to register and log in. After registering, you can join a group by entering the group's username and password.
I am having difficulty in checking whether the logged in user is part of the group. At the moment, if you enter the correct group's username and password, you will enter the group's portal no matter if you are a member or not.
Here's my code:

```
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Connection string");


        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select COUNT(*)FROM Groups WHERE GroupName='" + txtGroupUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtGroupPassword.Text + "'");

        cmd.Connection = con;



        int OBJ = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        if (OBJ > 0)
        {

            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into AssignGroups(MemberId,GroupId) Select Members.MemberId, Groups.GroupId From Members, Groups Where Members.Username= '" + lblRegistered.Text + "' And Groups.GroupName= '" + txtGroupUsername.Text + "'";





            Response.Redirect("GroupMembersM.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Visible = true;

            lblError.Text = "Invalid username or password";

        }
    }
```

At the moment, I have an AssignGroups table in my database which gets the memberId from the member's table and GroupId from the group's table.
What code could I use to check whether my memberId and GroupId match with the group's username and password.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

you could add a 3rd column to the AssignGroups table and call it Enabled / Authed etc

Then when adding the user to the group set this to true, you could then do a select against the mmeber and group ID's

```
select * from AssignGroups where groupid=@group and memberid=@member and enabled=1
```

you could also add in a value to each user called group which would then hold the groupid and do verification if column contains the value

```
select * from user where memberid=@id and groupid=@group
```

You could also allow for multiple group membership by doing a seperator so

```
update members set [name, email, group] values [@name, @email, @group]
command.add.parameterswithvalue("@name", value)
command.add.parameterswithvalue("@email", value)
command.add.parameterswithvalue("@group", value + "-" + value + "-" + value)
```

then when you bring it back you could do a .contains or string.split on the result and then check